# Laravel 5 Authentication: Call to a member function getEmailForPasswordReset() on null

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm using the authentication included with laravel 5.2

I have a problem at reset password form.

When I submit email, it returns this error:

> Call to a member function getEmailForPasswordReset() on null

I found this cause by the following code:

```
$user->getEmailForPasswordReset()
```

the `$user` is `null`

In addition, I try to change `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker` at function `emailResetLink`

```
return $this->mailer->send($view, compact('token', 'user'), function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
        $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());

        if (! is_null($callback)) {
            call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
        }
    });
```

I change:    compact('token', 'user') -> ['token'=>$token, 'user2'=>$user]

And `$user->getEmailForPasswordReset()` -> `$user2->getEmailForPasswordReset()`

It works well!

Can you help me figure out what I did wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely not in laravel files, so stop looking there and messing with the code, because you risk breaking more stuff than you will fix and also it will be overwritten once you do composer update.

The $user is null because the system cannot find the user you want to send a password reset link to. It would be more helpful to see your controller that implements the password resetting (submitting). Laravel comes with a pretty good starting point and you should not overengineer it unless needed: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-routing

So the method for sending reset links would look something like this:

```
public function postEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

        $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Password reset link sent');

            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'User not found');
        }
    }
```

As you see there's no User objects involved for you to handle.

Comment: Thanks @Tadas, I think the problem is still the $user cannot assign to the mail template. I've fixed it by override the function sendResetLinkEmail in PasswordController, and I don't need change any Laravel core.