# Laravel 5.2 password reset returns the fatal error: “Call to a member function getEmailForPasswordReset() on null”

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181343/laravel-5-authentication-call-to-a-member-function-getemailforpasswordreset-o), but I couldn’t comment on it or follow the question author’s advice to fix my problem.

Password reset was already set up and worked, I got back to it to check translation strings, and started getting this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmailForPasswordReset() on null (View: /home/vagrant/code/ecc/resources/views/emails/password.blade.php)`

I didn’t use source control for the project, so I couldn’t find out when exactly it stopped working. The only things that I changed in my password controller, were `getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse()` and `getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse()` to AJAXify my forms. Almost the same exact code runs in another project, but on the same Homestead, and it works. I checked the whole chain of calls, and unsurprisingly, there's nothing wrong with it—a user object becomes null somewhere during view rendering:

`8. at Mailer->getView('emails.password', array('token' => 'd81d3190958330e2a4e0552db07a1efc80d1768eddde0447f8efb9e588719ff4', 'user' => object(User), 'message' => object(Message))) in Mailer.php line 323`

`4. at CompilerEngine->get('/home/vagrant/code/ecc/resources/views/emails/password.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'token' => 'd81d3190958330e2a4e0552db07a1efc80d1768eddde0447f8efb9e588719ff4', 'user' => null, 'message' => object(Message), 'locale' => 'en')) in View.php line 149`

`3. at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/vagrant/code/ecc/storage/framework/views/469f1ba57eac0cc812c6c63e33641df67f64c100.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'token' => 'd81d3190958330e2a4e0552db07a1efc80d1768eddde0447f8efb9e588719ff4', 'user' => null, 'message' => object(Message), 'locale' => 'en')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59`

So, Mailer gets a user as a retreived object, but then it becomes null during view rendering. I tried reinstalling everything, `vagrant destroy`, `dump-autoload`, `clear-compiled`, removing all compiled views, I’m also not using Laravel Auto Presenter, or anything similar that tries to automatically wrap the user model in a decorator when it's passed into a view.

Can you please advise something? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here’s my controller, as requested:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;


    protected $subject;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');

        $this->subject = trans('emails.password_reset.subject');
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showResetForm($request, $token = null)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        $email = $request->input('email');

        return view('reset')->with(compact('token', 'email'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for after the reset link has been successfully sent.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for after the reset link could not be sent.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give in proper format so that we can read and answer

Comment: Variable $user used in view, on which you call function getEmailForPasswordReset() is null (empty/not set). All is in the error message

Comment: @VijayanandPremnath What should I change or add to make it easier on your eyes?

Comment: @Autista_z I understand. What I don’t understant, is why, because it’s vanilla Laravel.

Comment: @Banandrew give us you controller function, so we can see, what are you making there.

Comment: @Autista_z I edited the question. As you can see, it’s pretty much your regular Laravel’s PasswordController—I override only a couple of methods that have nothing to do with the problem, which I’m sure of, because the same code works in a different project. Everything else that’s responsible for password resetting is just Laravel.

Comment: @rakeshgoyal How it’s supposed to help, if what auth middleware does, it blocks AJAX requests and redirects unauthenticated users to login page? Either way, I tried, and it did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers) class to append a couple of variables to all views, one of them being `$user` that stores `Auth::user()`. Needless to say, this variable—which is obviously null, because a user is not logged in when it’s returned during password reset—overwrites a `$user` variable that Mailer passes further down the chain.

The solution is to either rename a $user variable in a view composer, use a custom password broker to overwrite `emailResetLink()` and change the variable name there, or pass an array of specific views in ComposerServiceProvider instead of a “*” as a wildcard.